# Не отображает результат валидации (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

При обновлении записи выводит session('success'), но в случае пустых поле не выводит session('errorr'), в чем может быть проблема?
Контроллер:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validate = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'type_sklad' => 'required',
    ]);
    if(Sklad::create($request->all())){
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Склад создан');
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Все поля должны быть заполнены');
}
```

View:

```
 @if(session('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            {{session('success')}}
        </div>
    @endif

    @if(session('error'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {{session('error')}}
        </div>
    @endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что Вы никогда не достигните `session('error')`, валидация порождает свое исключение (`throw new ValidationException` под капотом).

Обрабатывайте [ошибки по переменной](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) `$errors` в blade:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```